# Python Tkinter Inherit DataFrame between classes

Tags: pandas, class, dataframe, tkinter

I'm having an issues and I would kindly ask you to help me as I am not able to find a solution. 
Basically I am trying to inherit the DataFrame loaded into a variable in one Class (Window1) and I'm trying to use the same DataFrame in another Class (Window1). Please find below my current simplified code (Thank you):

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
import time, os, random, string
from datetime import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime
import pandas as pd

class Page(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container=tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid()
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames={}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):
            frame=F(container, self)
            self.frames[F]=frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        start_btn = tk.Button(self, text = "Start >>>", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageTwo), width = 10, activebackground = "#ffffff", relief="flat").grid()

        pass

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.browse_btn = tk.Button(self, text="     Browse     ", command=self.select_file)
        self.browse_btn.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=290, pady=10, columnspan=3, sticky="w")

        self.browse_entry = tk.Entry(self, text="", width=30)
        self.browse_entry.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=100, pady=10, sticky="w")

        self.continue_btn = tk.Button(self, text="Continue >>",  borderwidth=2, width=10, bg="#00c441", fg="#ffffff", command=lambda:[self.print_df(), controller.show_frame(PageThree)])
        self.continue_btn.grid(row=19, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=312, pady=5, sticky="w")
        self.continue_btn.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    def select_file(self):

        self.path = filedialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension="*.csv", filetypes = (("csv files","*.csv"),("All Files", "*.*")))
        self.browse_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.browse_entry.insert(0, self.path)
        ###following DataFrame I would like to use in in the PageThree class.
        self.df = pd.read_csv(self.path)

    def print_df(self):
        return self.df.head()


class PageThree(PageTwo):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        PageTwo.__init__(self, parent, controller)
        start_btn = tk.Button(self, text = "Data Frame", command=self.funct01, width = 10).grid()

    def funct01(self):
    ##this is where I would like to utilize the DataFrame (inside the function)
        instance=PageTwo(parent,controller)
        print(instance.select_file(self))


if __name__=="__main__":
    app=Page()
    app.geometry("400x400+100+100")
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to ask the `Page` instance (`controller`) to return the `PageTwo` instance, and you need to store the `controller` in the `PageTwo` "constructor".

I was not aware that you can hash a class definition (use it has the key of a dictionary).

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
import time, os, random, string
from datetime import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime
import pandas as pd

class Page(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container=tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid()
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames={}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):
            frame=F(container, self)
            self.frames[F]=frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def getFrame(self, frame):
        return self.frames[frame]

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        start_btn = tk.Button(self, text = "Start >>>", command=lambda:controller.show_frame(PageTwo), width = 10, activebackground = "#ffffff", relief="flat").grid()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.browse_btn = tk.Button(self, text="     Browse     ", command=self.select_file)
        self.browse_btn.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=290, pady=10, columnspan=3, sticky="w")

        self.browse_entry = tk.Entry(self, text="", width=30)
        self.browse_entry.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=100, pady=10, sticky="w")

        self.continue_btn = tk.Button(self, text="Continue >>",  borderwidth=2, width=10, bg="#00c441", fg="#ffffff", command=lambda:[self.print_df(), controller.show_frame(PageThree)])
        self.continue_btn.grid(row=19, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=312, pady=5, sticky="w")
        self.continue_btn.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    def select_file(self):

        self.path = filedialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension="*.csv", filetypes = (("csv files","*.csv"),("All Files", "*.*")))
        self.browse_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.browse_entry.insert(0, self.path)
        ###following DataFrame I would like to use in in the PageThree class.
        self.df = pd.read_csv(self.path)

    def print_df(self):
        return self.df.head()

class PageThree(PageTwo):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        PageTwo.__init__(self, parent, controller)
        start_btn = tk.Button(self, text = "Data Frame", command=self.funct01, width = 10).grid()

    def funct01(self):
        instance = self.controller.getFrame(PageTwo)
        dataFrame = instance.df
        print(dataFrame.head())

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=Page()
    app.geometry("400x400+100+100")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Now I understand. Thank you